# Two transistor switches on a dual coil latching relay

Tags: transistors, esp8266, latching-relay

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fLc3Hv.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

I have a small project in which I have an ESP8266-12E OUTPUT pin going through a 2N2222 transistor as a switch that energizes the set side of a dual coil latching relay.  When the relay is set the ESP is turned off and another ESP is turned on.  I want to put another 2N2222 transistor as a switch to energize the reset side of the relay from the second ESP's OUTPUT pin.
When the reset is activated the second ESP is turned off and the first one is reactivated.
I have included a drawing of the wiring I think will work.  Is there some reason this shouldn't work.  Will it bounce back and forth?  I don't see why it should as the activation pins are turned off when the power to the ESP's are cut.  I know this has been asked before but this suggests a different solution.

Since I could not find a dual coil DPDT latching relay in the schematic resources I put two single coil SPDT back to back to simulate one.  Just image them as one. The top is the positive side of the set and reset coils.

Comment: A schematic would be better. This is a wiring diagram. Without knowing which precise 2N2222 you have (P2N2222 vs PN2222, for example) there's no way of knowing which lead is the collector or emitter. Also, are you just basically looking to have a powered MCU able to switch itself off and turn on the other one?

Comment: You can add a schematic in using the CircuitLab button on the editor toolbar. Double-click a component to edit its properties. 'R' = rotate, 'H' = horizontal flip. 'V' = vertical flip. 

Note that when you use the CircuitLab button on the editor toolbar and "Save and Insert" on the editor an editable schematic is saved in your post. That makes it easy for us to copy and edit in our answers. You don't need a CircuitLab account, no screengrabs, no image uploads, no background grid.

Comment: Thanks. A few questions. (1) Why not use relays that are designed with coil voltages where your +17 V supply would be appropriate? This would alleviate the need for one NTE1904. (2) You don't need an LDO for converting from +17 V to +3.3 V. That's not "low drop-out" by any measure. (3) Do you know your active MCU will be able to supply BJT base current long enough for the relay to completely switch, if in fact, the relay is removing power from that MCU? (4) I/O pins float as the MCU is powering up. It may be nice to have "hold-down" resistors for the BJTs, too.

Comment: I have added another input to the ESP1 BJT.  There is also an RF signal input on this. The reason for the 3.3v relay is that on the one side I use a BJT to activate the relay's SET coil through MCU or RF but the other side was just the MCU pin output which was 3.3v hence the relay's voltage.  I could change it but for now it is.  RF/MCU BJT work fine in switching relay but MCU pin doesn't have enough current so looking to add BJT to RESET.  Didn't know about LDO so could change it in future (suggestions?) Hold-down resistor?  Don't know I am not EE.  But am willing to add if needed.

Comment: When I try to RESET relay with MCU I/O pin it tries but stays on same MCU so a loop.  That's why I want to add the other BJT to that side to get it to activate RESET.

Comment: To clarify, I already have this built and the MCU/RF already switch the SET side of the relay so I know that part works.  This is why I am not going to replace relay right now, but it is a good idea in the future.  I looked up LDO regulators and found the LM1117T could be used.  Cheaper also.  I hope someone will look at this and let me know if they think it will work or any modifications that are needed to make it work.

Comment: As far as the hold-down/pull-down resistor.  Is this to bleed off any excess current so that when the second BJT activates the RESET coil there is no current in the first BJT that will reactivate the SET side setting up a jittering effect.  Jittering between SET and RESET.  What size would I need and where would I put it?

Comment: So I put a 10K resistor between base and emitter and problem solved.  Without adding another BJT to the RESET coil.  Now every time the SET BJT goes off the ESP2 does its thing and then the I/O pin activates the RESET.  I have been working on this for some time.  Even asking about it here.  No-one ever suggested this simple solution.  THANKS!!!

Comment: What is `RF_signal`? If it alternates below about 0.6VDC, the diode it connects to will cease flowing current into R1, and Q3 will shut off. If this is happening very rapidly, Relay3 may stay activated, but realize it is getting fast pulses of current. This tends to create electrical noise and problems elsewhere. To solve, add a small cap between base and emitter of Q3, 0.1µF might be enough. Then the cap would supply power to the base between RF pulses. It will also slow down the response time of Q3 slightly, so may take some experimentation. An oscilloscope would be helpful here.